# Sass: Overriding default variables of imported stylesheets

Tags: variables, import, sass, default

### Problem

About overriding `!default` variables -- I have two `.sass` files:

**main.sass**

```
$variable: black

@import "_another_import.sass"
@import "_import.sass"
```

---

**_import.sass**

```
$variable: blue !default

body
    background: $variable
```

---

The `$variable` resolves to `blue` in the compiled CSS:

```
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

However, if I specify the overriding variable value right before I import the `_import.sass` stylesheet, Sass compiles it to `black`:

**main.sass**

```
@import "_another_import.sass"

$variable: black

@import "_import.sass"
```

---

### Question

Is this behavior intended? Is there a way to declare overrides for `!default` variable values earlier than the `!default` values are declared in imports (maybe even in a separate file)?

---

### Actual setup (for reference)

My actual setup is a little bit more complicated than that. I am using [Myg](https://github.com/jonhue/myg) (NPM components) with [myg-rails](https://github.com/jonhue/myg-rails) (generating file structure to customize variables) and Webpack. So I have a `myg.sass` file loading `_variables.sass` and `_myg.sass`. `_variables.sass` loads a couple of other files which define the variables. `_myg.sass` imports the Myg (NPM) components. I verified that when I define a variable in `_variables.sass` and use it + set a default in a Myg component, the default will override the already set value.

Comment: You want backgound blue or black ??

Comment: @Abhijeet `black`

Comment: What sass compiler are you using?

Comment: @miir I'm using Sass with webpack using the sass-loader.

Comment: Can you share your real `main.sass` your webpack config?

Comment: @miir My actual setup is a little bit more complicated than that. I am using [Myg](https://github.com/jonhue/myg) (NPM components) with [myg-rails](https://github.com/jonhue/myg-rails) (generating file structure to customize variables) and Webpack. So I have a `myg.sass` file loading `_variables.sass` and `_myg.sass`. `_variables.sass` loads a couple of other files which define the variables. `_myg.sass` imports the Myg (NPM) components. I verified that when I define a variable in `_variables.sass` and use it + set a default in a Myg component, the default will override the already set value.

Comment: Are you sure you don't set the background to blue in the _another_import.sass?

Comment: @ochs.tobi Yes, I tested the problem with a variety of properties.

Comment: I think @miir answer is the right one, however can you verify that none of your `_another_import.sass` are actually defining the `$variable` or importing other files which are doing the same? Remember that now you have the `!global` flag to avoid issues with local contexts

Comment: @jonhue Are there specific Myg components that are causing the issue? Which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, what you are doing should work. The resulting behavior you're experiencing is irregular and *not* intended.

From [sass-lang docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_default):

> You can assign to variables if they aren't already assigned by adding the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that **if the variable has already been assigned to, it won't be re-assigned**, but if it doesn't have a value yet, it will be given one.

I suspect there may be something else at play that we need to investigate.

I've verified the correct behavior with these files:

### Sass source:

**_t1.sass**

```
div
    margin: 0
```

**_t2.sass**

```
$c: blue !default

body
    background: $c
```

**main.sass**

```
$c: black

@import '_t1.sass'
@import '_t2.sass'
```

---

### CSS result:

```
div {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

It is black as intended.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is :-
1) If you want black background then you simply do like this

```
// main.sass

@import "_another_import.sass";
@import "_import.sass";

// _import.sass
$variable: black;
body{
    background-color: $variable !important;
}
```

But my suggestion is that your file structure like this

```
    @import "_variable"; /*Define Variable in separate file & in that file declare $variable*/  
    @import "_another_import.sass";
    @import "_import.sass";

body{
    background-color: $variable !important;
}
```

Comment: The example just illustrates my problem. There is no way for me to restructure the files. My question is whether or not there is something I'm doing wrong preventing it from working as I'd expect. I'm not looking for an entirely different solution.

Comment: $variable: blue !default , remove this except this everything is fine and its  standard if you declare a variable after import so your code like my first suggestion

Comment: I know, I just have to override a variable that is declared as `!default`. My issue is, that my custom set variable only takes precedence over the default variable if I declare it right before I import the file setting the variable default.

Comment: you have to use ; after every import and I think then that issue is not came .. otherwise share code with me .. so that i debug because its very strange I never face this type of issue ..

Comment: I'm using Sass not Scss. You can find the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what `!default` does. It is saying if variable is not assigned, use this value.

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I want to override a default variable value (specified by an NPM package) before I import it.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now, this question is around the `@import "_another_import.sass"` breaking the default variable override pattern. I am betting there is some malformed SASS in that import that the compiler is not choking on. It has happened to me a number of times. What happens when you reduce that import down to just a couple valid styles, same behavior?